# Overflow and carry flags with three addends

Tags: c

I'm writing a project in C.

I need to check if I should set CARRY or OVERFLOW bits when doing addition, substraction, division and multiplication. The only problem I have is that I have to do it with three addends. Example a = a + b + c.

What is the easiest way to check if these two bits should be set?

EDIT: I have to write a system which sets these flags after each of these operations. All numbers are signed integers.

EDIT 2: My solution for two integers:

```
#define MAXINT 32767

short int a, b, c;
short int i, j, k;

if (MAXINT - a < b) // carry

i=a; i>>15; i&=0x01;
j=b; j>>15; j&=0x01;
c=a+b;
k=c; k>>15; k&=0x01;
if(i==j && i!=k) //overflow
```

Comment: There are no CARRY or OVERFLOW bits in C. Is this about a certain platform? A way to catch overflows in C portably?

Comment: The question is not stated well, but I suspect OP's assignment is to write a program that simulates a simple CPU that has these flags.

Comment: ah, so you are not doing the calculation bit by bit?

Comment: Well, show us how you did it with 2 operands and we’ll see how we can help for 3 operands. (you said the only problem you have is making it work for 3 operands)

Comment: I added my solution for two integers.

Comment: if you can do it with 2 addends, do that thing again with the output and the 3rd

Comment: But is that the correct way? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

In C, using `short` or `int` or `long`, overflow is assumed to *never* occur.  The compiler takes advantage of that and thus may not behave as one expects *after* an overflow.  To be truly portable, code must insure overflow does not occur.

Let's just use 2 variables: `a`, `b`.

```
#include <limits.h>
int safe_add(int a, int b) {
  if (a >= 0) {
    if (b > INT_MAX - a) {
      ; /* handle overflow */
    }
  } else {
    if (b < INT_MIN - a) {
      ; /* handle underflow */
    }
  }
  return a + b;
}
```

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/simpler-method-to-detect-int-overflow